# Mr. Smith is the president of the corporation who will not accept our proposal

Tags: grammar

My professor holds that this is a good sentence, since *who* agrees with the subject, *Mr. Smith*.  It sounds horrible to me.

> Mr. Smith is the president of the corporation who will not accept our proposal.

Is this a good sentence?

Comment: It all depends on what it's intended to mean.  It's a good sentence if it is supposed to mean that there are several presidents of the corporation and that one of those presidents, Mr. Smith, will not accept our proposal.

Comment: Is it a person or a business that will not accept your proposal?

Comment: @Jim It's a good sentence in any case. Whether or not it's the correct one to express what the speaker wishes to say is a different matter.

Comment: Well, if you ask the US Supreme Court or Mitt Romney, corporations are people and therefore the sentence can be valid.

Comment: @Shadur; to a lawyer *persons* is not the same as *people*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP is right that it's a horrible sentence.

Consider some alternatives, starting with the original.

> Mr. Smith is the president of the corporation who will not accept our proposal

The sentence as given is grammatical if it is interpreted to mean:

> Mr. Smith is the corporation president who will not accept our proposal.

But it sounds more like an ungrammatical attempt to say:

> Mr. Smith is the president of the corporation that will not accept our proposal

Since the original sentence is ambiguous, it would be a mistake to describe it as "good." It is a poorly written grammatical sentence.

Comment: In what way is the original sentence ambiguous? If you're saying that 'The sentence as it stands means X, but it may be a wrong way of trying to say Y', all of English comes into this category.

Comment: The point is not that it "may be" a wrong way of saying Y but that it *sounds like* a wrong way of saying Y.

Comment: But it also sounds like a right way of saying X. It _is_ a right way of saying X.

Comment: Since it sounds like two different things, it is, as I said, *ambiguous*

Comment: Not to Jim, OP's professor, or me.

Answer (score 5):

Well, let's start with a rhetorical question. Would you consider the following to be a "good" English sentence?

> Mr. Smith is the executive who will not accept our proposal.

I definitely consider this to be a "good" English sentence. It relies on the fact that there are multiple executives of which Mr. Smith is the one who's not impressed with the proposal.

Similarly, your sentence,

> Mr. Smith is the president of the corporation who will not accept our proposal.

is a "good" English sentence if the following sentence holds true,

> Mr. Smith is the president of the corporation, among all of the presidents of the corporation, who will not accept our proposal.

Answer (score 1):

Fun sentence!

The disquiet here is because of the use of determiners with a preposition in the middle:

> **the** president of **the** corporation

We expect the relative pronoun *who* to describe the noun that immediately precedes it. The sentence is grammatical if *the president of the corporation* is understood to be a noun phrase with *president* as the headword.

Writing the sentence as:

> Mr. Smith is the president of the corporation that will not accept our proposal.

gives the corporation (and strips Smith of) agency, changing the meaning.

N.B.
I've only given this a little thought, and would love to have problems with my logic pointed out, but this pattern (det n prep det n) isn't uncommon when it comes to titles:

- the head of the committee
- a man of the cloth

The first shows how changing the relative pronoun changes agency; the second can illustrate how important it is to recognize the first noun as the headword of the NP.

> Sharon is the head of the committee who closed the deal.

is different to

> Sharon is the head of the committee that closed the deal.

In the first case, Sharon did it; in the second, it was the committee. From this I'd argue that the OP's sentence is a grammatical construction that conveys a precise meaning.

Similarly,

> Savonarola was a/the man of the cloth who was burned at the stake.

is grammatical.

> Savonarola was a/the man of the cloth that was burned at the stake.

is also grammatical, but almost nonsensical as it sounds like Savonarola was made of cloth.